# Calendar Date Picker In Xamarin Forms UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, datepicker

How to create a calendar type date picker in Xamarin forms UWP app.

So far I have tried this:

```
 <Image Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Source="Images/datePicker.png" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" Margin="-40,0,40,0" HorizontalOptions="End">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnSelectDOBCommand}"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>

 public void OnSelectDOB(object obj)
    {         
        dateOfBuildDatePicker = UserDialogs.Instance.DatePrompt(new DatePromptConfig { MaximumDate = DateTime.Today, OnAction = (result) => SetDateOfBirth(result), IsCancellable = true });
    }
```

But this displays the date picker control on top left corner of the screen.
Is there a way to customize it so that it should display the date picker right next to the field where I click or is there any other control which can help me achieve this functionality.(Below image is the behavior that I am expecting)

Any help is appreciated[image: ![Calendar Date Picker]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M04Rl.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to consume a special control on UWP platform, you can try [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).

Firstly, create a custom control:

```
public class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
{
}
```

Then make a custom renderer on UWP:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomDatePicker), typeof(CustomDatePickerRenderer))]
namespace Demo.UWP
{
    public class CustomDatePickerRenderer : ViewRenderer<DatePicker, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CalendarDatePicker>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CalendarDatePicker datePicker = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CalendarDatePicker();
                SetNativeControl(datePicker);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At last, use it on your forms project:

```
<StackLayout>
    <local:CustomDatePicker HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Alternatively, you can try native view: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/

Answer (score 1):

date value is always set to the current date even you selected a data. how to resolve this?

Comment: This should be considered as comment, not the answer

Answer (score 0):

Changing the date value requires working with the date change events. See my working solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60449912/9523062